# Spring Batch job with job metadata and business data in separate datasources running very slow

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

Firstly, I'm pretty new to Spring Batch, so, sorry if this is entirely due to my own ignorance.

I have a Spring Batch job set up with two different datasources (one storing business data and the other storing the job metadata). I'm not using XA transactions in order to opt more for performance than reliability in this case (my boss's orders).

In order to make this work I have a concrete class `MyBatchConfigurer` which implements `BatchConfigurer`. I Autowire my metadata datasource in the configurer class and then the business data datasource is wired to the readers and writers in my job configuration.
It seems to work well enough, but it slows down the job significantly (from 20 seconds to 130 seconds on my test table).
Going through the logs seems to show that there is a significant lag when it hits "Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection".
I thought maybe I can change the synchronization settings (NEVER/ALWAYS/PER-TRANSACTION), but that didn't help.
Is there a way to not take such a hit while retaining the two datasource setup?

P.S. It is probably significant that this job runs a bunch of partitioned steps using AsyncTaskExecutor at the moment - but in the final iteration partitions will be run on separate machines via a messaging queue setup.